# how to find textbox value in repeater when click on anchor link

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a repeter in which there is textbox .Now I want to get the value of  textbox  (txtDestroyQty) when user click on link.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptDestroy" runat="server"  >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
            <td><%#Eval("productName") %></td>
            <td><%#Eval("ProductId") %></td>
            <td><%#Eval("Attid") %></td>
            <td><%#Eval("vname") %></td>
            <td><%#Eval("PendingQty") %></td>
            <td>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtDestroyQty" CssClass="txt" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                <a href="javascript:Destroy('<%#Eval("vendorId") %>','<%#Eval("ProductId") %>','<%#Eval("Attid") %>')">Destroy</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

I have this jQuery:

```
function Destroy(vid, Pid, Attid) {
    var obj = {};
    obj.vid = vid;
    obj.pid = Pid;
    obj.attid = Attid;
    obj.pendingqty = pendingqty;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/stocks/Rejection.aspx/DestroyItem",
        data: JSON.stringify(obj),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {

            if (data.d == "Y")
                window.location.href = '/stocks/rejection.aspx';
            else
                alert('Not Destroyed');

        },
        error: function (result) {
            alert('went wrong');
        }

    });
}
```

I tried this

```
var pendingqty = $('#txtDestroyQty').val();
var value = $(this).closest('tr').find('input.txt').val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `this` as a context:

```
<a href="javascript:Destroy(this, '<%#Eval("vendorId") %>','<%#Eval("ProductId") %>','<%#Eval("Attid") %>')">Destroy</a>
```

Now you have to change this in the js function:

```
function Destroy(el, vid, Pid, Attid) { // <----get this as el
    var obj = {};
    obj.vid = vid;
    obj.pid = Pid;
    obj.attid = Attid;
    obj.pendingqty = $(el).prev().val(); // now assign it here
```

Comment: e1.value give the result 'undefined'

Comment: var value = $(this).closest('td').find('input.[txtDestroyQty']).val();

Comment: I tried This also ...            var value = $(this).closest('td').find('[id*=txtDestroyQty]').val();

Answer (score 0):

Use a server side control like `HyperLink` with the ID property set. then you could use this.id to get it's ID. and, then just replace HyperLink ID with your TextBox ID. This will give you the client side ID of your text boxes for each row.

NOTE: this.id returns undefined error for anchor `<a>`. I'm not sure why at this stage. This is a common trick we do with Repeater or any other list controls.

Use the following instead of your anchor link.

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" onclick="javascript:alert(this.id.replace('HyperLink1', 'txtDestroyQty'));" runat="server">Destry</asp:HyperLink>
```

Comment: What do you want me to do? Did you try my suggestion?